# string_view to const reference string gets invalidated

Tags: c++

I came across this simple code today.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m = {
      {"asdf", 123},
      {"dsdfesjfdaslkfjasljlasfjlasjfakdlsfjasklfajsklfjaskljlf", 123},
      {"ldfjaslk}sfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
      {"ldafjaslk}sfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
      {"ldjaksdfjfjaslk}sfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
      {"ldfjaslk}sfdasfdsfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
      {"ldfjaslk}sfjalsksfdasdfdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
      {"ldfjaslk}sfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj", 1},
  };

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string_view, int>> vec;

  for (auto& [s, i] : m) {
    vec.push_back(std::make_pair(s, i));
    std::cout << vec.back().first << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Basically, vector is created with the element of the map. The thing is that it instead converts the string to string_view when inserting to the vector. I thought this would be okay as we are using const string reference to construct string_view, and the string will be available throughout the lifespan of the vector.

But when I checked the output, it showed seemingly corrupted data.

```
�/�U.�Usfdasdfdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj
�/�U.�Usfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj
@/�U.�Ukdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj
�/�U.�Usfjalskdfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj
@/�U.�Udfjlkdasjfaslkfjaskdljflaskdfjdaslkfjasdlkfjasdlj
.�Usljlasfjlasjfakdlsfjasklfajsklfjaskljlf
asdf
```

I guess string_view in the vector no longer points to the proper element. But why this has happend? I assumed that the unordered_map would be immutable while iterating so the address of the key element would not have changed.

Godbolt link : https://godbolt.org/z/dePdv5

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dePdv5

Comment: Wouldn't `std::make_pair` make a copy of the string, and then vec store a reference to the copy?

Comment: ahhh. So when I fixed it to `vec.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string_view(s), i));`, it fixed it.

But I wonder how would this not be a default behavior?

Comment: It works much better with `emplace_back` and without `make_pair`: [**Live Demo on coliru**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9baf994a1369ddf) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `make_pair` you generate a temporary object of type `std::pair<std::string, int>`. I would expect the conversion to `std::pair<std::string_view, int>` to throw an error, but apparently it works.

Anyhow,  `std::string_view` is non-owning, so as soon as the temporary object is destroyed (at the end of the line `;`) it becomes dangling.

You shouldn't make a new pair. Try `emplace_back` with the key and value.

Comment: cool. I have been told to avoid emplace_back as it might call the unexpected ctor. But I guess this is the only case I find it useful :P

Comment: The conversion exists because `std::string` to `std::string_view` is an implicit conversion. You kinda see why people were "upset" about that decision.

Comment: @passerby seriously? I think I'm joining the "upset club" now.